# Put a border on a feature in OpenLayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to put a red border around an OpenLayers3 feature.  The feature is an icon created from an image. The icon can be square, circular, diamond-shaped, etc.  Is this possible? Here is what I am trying now:

```js
var iconurl = "http://www.example.com/pic.png";
var symbolStyle = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(({
      opacity: 0.55,
      src: iconurl,                   
    })),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      width: 2,
      color: 'red'
    })
  })
];
```

Comment: Not really possible but you could add another Circle or RegularShape style and put the stroke/fill on that as a background style with the icon in the foreground.

Comment: It's possible. I have answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738247/openlayers3-how-to-add-a-colored-border-around-a-marker-icon/44738320#44738320