# Openlayers3: How to add a colored border around a marker icon?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, openlayers-3

OpenLayers 3 renders's its marker icons as images on a canvas. Markers can have transparent background with non regular image icon. Is it possible to add a colored border of specific thickness and color using `ol.interaction.Select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to achieve this by modifying the [Icon Pixel Operations](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-negative.html?q=dynamic%20marker) example on the OpenLayers website. It is possible to work  with the icon image canvas in the `styleFunction` that `ol.interaction.select` provides, and first create a colored fill of the same shape as icon, and then write icon back on it, essentially giving a colored border to the icon. Which looks like this:

Non Active State:

[image]

[image]

**Working [CodePen](https://codepen.io/shaunakv1/pen/awyepv).**

**Here's the modified style function :**

```
style: function(feature) {
    var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var activeColor = "red"; //set border color
      var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
          s = 2,  // thickness scale
          i = 0,  // iterator
          x = 2,  // final x position
          y = 2;  // final y position

      //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
      canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
      canvas.height = image.height + s + s;

      // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
      for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
      ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);

      // fill with color
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
      ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // draw original image in normal mode
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,image.width, image.height);

      //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
      return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          src: undefined,
          img: canvas,
          imgSize: canvas ? [canvas.width, canvas.height] : undefined
        }))
      });

  }
```

**Full Code:**

```js
function createStyle(src, img) {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
      src: src,
      img: img,
      imgSize: img ? [img.width, img.height] : undefined
    }))
  });
}

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]));
iconFeature.set('style', createStyle('https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/examples/data/icon.png', undefined));

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
     new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      style: function(feature) {
        return feature.get('style');
      },
      source: new ol.source.Vector({features: [iconFeature]})
    })
  ],
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});


var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  style: function(feature) {
    var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var activeColor = "red"; //set border color
      var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
          s = 2,  // thickness scale
          i = 0,  // iterator
          x = 2,  // final x position
          y = 2;  // final y position
      
      //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
      canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
      canvas.height = image.height + s + s;
    
      // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
      for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
      ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);
    
      // fill with color
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
      ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
      // draw original image in normal mode
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,image.width, image.height);
    
      //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
      return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
          crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
          src: undefined,
          img: canvas,
          imgSize: canvas ? [canvas.width, canvas.height] : undefined
        }))
      });
    
  }
});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: if we want the border's color to be able to change due to an attribute in the marker. Then would it re-render the color if there are changes in the marker ?

Comment: yes, in that case you would use the same technique to set a base border color  base d on the attribute. You can still have a hover color

Comment: I want it to be present from the beginning and not only when someone hovers over the icon. Also, when there are changes received from the server then it should change the background color.